# Column Names that need to be selected from a table comes from another table

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I have two tables, table A contains the data in generic named columns. Which in other table B, I have a comma separated list of column names of table A.

Sample Data:

Table A:

```
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+------+
| CODE | C1  | C2  | C3  | C4  | C5  |  C6  | C7  | M1  | M2  | M3  | M4  | M5 |  M6  |
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+------+
| A1   | 102 | 275 | 400 | -55 |  -1 | 2779 |   5 | 157 | 236 | 332 | -94 |  7 | 2209 |
| A2   | 162 | 209 | 330 | -71 |  -4 | 1041 |   7 | 188 | 264 | 349 |  -3 | -8 | 3863 |
| A3   | 124 | 237 | 334 | -71 |   3 | 2086 |  24 | 126 | 299 | 366 | -36 | -8 | 1416 |
| A4   | 154 | 267 | 360 | -15 |   7 | 3900 |  24 | 103 | 260 | 316 | -92 |  2 | 3247 |
| A5   | 157 | 240 | 361 | -86 |   8 | 3871 | -13 | 123 | 296 | 380 | -80 | -6 | 3743 |
| A6   | 138 | 268 | 388 | -27 | -10 | 2939 | -23 | 181 | 229 | 393 | -46 | -6 | 1355 |
| A7   | 117 | 267 | 353 | -92 |  -6 | 3273 |  10 | 194 | 243 | 317 | -91 |  4 | 2508 |
| A8   | 138 | 207 | 343 | -67 |   3 | 1558 | -18 | 143 | 242 | 308 | -51 |  4 | 3955 |
| A9   | 175 | 225 | 359 | -11 |  -1 | 2344 |  13 | 174 | 229 | 380 |  -3 |  4 | 2611 |
| B1   | 137 | 295 | 364 | -48 |  -2 | 3827 |  24 | 169 | 257 | 304 | -58 |  9 | 1534 |
| B2   | 155 | 231 | 339 | -39 |  -1 | 2895 | -19 | 107 | 251 | 305 |  -1 |  2 | 2208 |
| B3   | 166 | 251 | 363 | -42 |  -2 | 1766 |   6 | 128 | 272 | 371 | -27 |  7 | 3460 |
| B4   | 116 | 200 | 317 | -72 |  -6 | 1073 | -13 | 160 | 230 | 307 | -73 | -8 | 3393 |
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+------+
```

Table B:

```
+------+-------------------+
| CODE |    SELECT_COLS    |
+------+-------------------+
| A1   | C1,C2,C3,M1,M2,M3 |
| A2   | C1,C2,C3,M1,M2,M3 |
| A3   | C1,C2,C3,M1,M2,M3 |
| A4   | C1,C2,C3,C4,M1    |
| A5   | C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,M1 |
| A6   | C1,C2,C3,M1,M2    |
| A7   | C1,C2,C3,C4,M1,M2 |
| A8   | C1,C2,C3,C4,M1,M2 |
| A9   | C1,C2,C3,C4,M1,M2 |
| B1   | C1,C2,C3,C4,M1    |
| B2   | C1,C2,C3,C4,M1    |
| B3   | C1,C2,M1          |
| B4   | C1,M1             |
+------+-------------------+
```

Is there any way I can select only Columns specified in SELECT_COLS column of table B from table A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of the two potential solutions here require dynamic SQL or the use of PL/SQL and they will get you the **data** you require.

Oracle does not support selecting from dynamic columns; yes, you could use PL/SQL to dynamically build an SQL statement but when that statement runs it will have fixed columns. Also, if you have one set of data that wants `C1,C2,C3,M1,M2,M3` and another that wants `C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,M1` then do you want 6 columns of data (plus the code) and, if so, how will you know what the columns contain? Or do you want 8 columns of data (6 from the first and the extra 2 from the second) and, if so, how do you know that you don't just want all the columns; so wouldn't it be easier just to get the data for every column and set the values to `NULL` that aren't meant to be shown and then you can hide columns which are all `NULL` in your application tier.

So, instead of trying to get dynamic columns, select them as rows and then if you need to pivot them back to columns do it in whatever application tier you are using to access the database.

```sql
SELECT a.*
FROM   (
         SELECT Code, Key, Value
         FROM   tableA
         UNPIVOT (
           VALUE FOR KEY IN (
             C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, M1, M2, M3, M3, M4, M5, M6
           )
         )
       ) a
       INNER JOIN (
         TableB
       ) B
       ON ( a.code = b.code AND INSTR( b.select_cols, a.key ) > 0 )
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tableA ( CODE, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6 ) AS
SELECT 'A1', 102, 275, 400, -55, -1, 2779, 5, 157, 236, 332, -94, 7, 2209 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A2', 162, 209, 330, -71, -4, 1041, 7, 188, 264, 349, -3, -8, 3863 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A3', 124, 237, 334, -71, 3, 2086, 24, 126, 299, 366, -36, -8, 1416 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A4', 154, 267, 360, -15, 7, 3900, 24, 103, 260, 316, -92, 2, 3247 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A5', 157, 240, 361, -86, 8, 3871, -13, 123, 296, 380, -80, -6, 3743 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A6', 138, 268, 388, -27, -10, 2939, -23, 181, 229, 393, -46, -6, 1355 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A7', 117, 267, 353, -92, -6, 3273, 10, 194, 243, 317, -91, 4, 2508 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A8', 138, 207, 343, -67, 3, 1558, -18, 143, 242, 308, -51, 4, 3955 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A9', 175, 225, 359, -11, -1, 2344, 13, 174, 229, 380, -3, 4, 2611 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B1', 137, 295, 364, -48, -2, 3827, 24, 169, 257, 304, -58, 9, 1534 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B2', 155, 231, 339, -39, -1, 2895, -19, 107, 251, 305, -1, 2, 2208 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B3', 166, 251, 363, -42, -2, 1766, 6, 128, 272, 371, -27, 7, 3460 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B4', 116, 200, 317, -72, -6, 1073, -13, 160, 230, 307, -73, -8, 3393 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE tableB ( CODE, SELECT_COLS ) AS
SELECT 'A1', 'C1,C2,C3,M1,M2,M3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A2', 'C1,C2,C3,M1,M2,M3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A3', 'C1,C2,C3,M1,M2,M3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A4', 'C1,C2,C3,C4,M1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A5', 'C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,M1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A6', 'C1,C2,C3,M1,M2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A7', 'C1,C2,C3,C4,M1,M2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A8', 'C1,C2,C3,C4,M1,M2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A9', 'C1,C2,C3,C4,M1,M2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B1', 'C1,C2,C3,C4,M1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B2', 'C1,C2,C3,C4,M1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B3', 'C1,C2,M1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B4', 'C1,M1' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> CODE | KEY | VALUE
> :--- | :-- | ----:
> A1   | C1  |   102
> A1   | C2  |   275
> A1   | C3  |   400
> A1   | M1  |   157
> A1   | M2  |   236
> A1   | M3  |   332
> A1   | M3  |   332
> A2   | C1  |   162
> A2   | C2  |   209
> A2   | C3  |   330
> A2   | M1  |   188
> A2   | M2  |   264
> A2   | M3  |   349
> A2   | M3  |   349
> A3   | C1  |   124
> A3   | C2  |   237
> A3   | C3  |   334
> A3   | M1  |   126
> A3   | M2  |   299
> A3   | M3  |   366
> A3   | M3  |   366
> A4   | C1  |   154
> A4   | C2  |   267
> A4   | C3  |   360
> A4   | C4  |   -15
> A4   | M1  |   103
> A5   | C1  |   157
> A5   | C2  |   240
> A5   | C3  |   361
> A5   | C4  |   -86
> A5   | C5  |     8
> A5   | M1  |   123
> A6   | C1  |   138
> A6   | C2  |   268
> A6   | C3  |   388
> A6   | M1  |   181
> A6   | M2  |   229
> A7   | C1  |   117
> A7   | C2  |   267
> A7   | C3  |   353
> A7   | C4  |   -92
> A7   | M1  |   194
> A7   | M2  |   243
> A8   | C1  |   138
> A8   | C2  |   207
> A8   | C3  |   343
> A8   | C4  |   -67
> A8   | M1  |   143
> A8   | M2  |   242
> A9   | C1  |   175
> A9   | C2  |   225
> A9   | C3  |   359
> A9   | C4  |   -11
> A9   | M1  |   174
> A9   | M2  |   229
> B1   | C1  |   137
> B1   | C2  |   295
> B1   | C3  |   364
> B1   | C4  |   -48
> B1   | M1  |   169
> B2   | C1  |   155
> B2   | C2  |   231
> B2   | C3  |   339
> B2   | C4  |   -39
> B2   | M1  |   107
> B3   | C1  |   166
> B3   | C2  |   251
> B3   | M1  |   128
> B4   | C1  |   116
> B4   | M1  |   160
> ```

If you could have any of the rows and want them all as columns then just get them all and set the values to `NULL` if they aren't in the `select_cols` column:

```sql
SELECT a.code,
       CASE WHEN INSTR( b.select_cols, 'C1' ) > 0 THEN C1 END AS C1,
       CASE WHEN INSTR( b.select_cols, 'C2' ) > 0 THEN C2 END AS C2,
       CASE WHEN INSTR( b.select_cols, 'C3' ) > 0 THEN C3 END AS C3,
       CASE WHEN INSTR( b.select_cols, 'C4' ) > 0 THEN C4 END AS C4,
       CASE WHEN INSTR( b.select_cols, 'C5' ) > 0 THEN C5 END AS C5,
       CASE WHEN INSTR( b.select_cols, 'C6' ) > 0 THEN C6 END AS C6,
       CASE WHEN INSTR( b.select_cols, 'C7' ) > 0 THEN C7 END AS C7,
       CASE WHEN INSTR( b.select_cols, 'M1' ) > 0 THEN M1 END AS M1,
       CASE WHEN INSTR( b.select_cols, 'M2' ) > 0 THEN M2 END AS M2,
       CASE WHEN INSTR( b.select_cols, 'M3' ) > 0 THEN M3 END AS M3,
       CASE WHEN INSTR( b.select_cols, 'M4' ) > 0 THEN M4 END AS M4,
       CASE WHEN INSTR( b.select_cols, 'M5' ) > 0 THEN M5 END AS M5,
       CASE WHEN INSTR( b.select_cols, 'M6' ) > 0 THEN M6 END AS M6
FROM   tableA a
       INNER JOIN tableB b
       ON ( a.code = b.code )
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> CODE |  C1 |   C2 |   C3 |   C4 |   C5 |   C6 |   C7 |  M1 |   M2 |   M3 |   M4 |   M5 |   M6
> :--- | --: | ---: | ---: | ---: | ---: | ---: | ---: | --: | ---: | ---: | ---: | ---: | ---:
> A1   | 102 |  275 |  400 | null | null | null | null | 157 |  236 |  332 | null | null | null
> A2   | 162 |  209 |  330 | null | null | null | null | 188 |  264 |  349 | null | null | null
> A3   | 124 |  237 |  334 | null | null | null | null | 126 |  299 |  366 | null | null | null
> A4   | 154 |  267 |  360 |  -15 | null | null | null | 103 | null | null | null | null | null
> A5   | 157 |  240 |  361 |  -86 |    8 | null | null | 123 | null | null | null | null | null
> A6   | 138 |  268 |  388 | null | null | null | null | 181 |  229 | null | null | null | null
> A7   | 117 |  267 |  353 |  -92 | null | null | null | 194 |  243 | null | null | null | null
> A8   | 138 |  207 |  343 |  -67 | null | null | null | 143 |  242 | null | null | null | null
> A9   | 175 |  225 |  359 |  -11 | null | null | null | 174 |  229 | null | null | null | null
> B1   | 137 |  295 |  364 |  -48 | null | null | null | 169 | null | null | null | null | null
> B2   | 155 |  231 |  339 |  -39 | null | null | null | 107 | null | null | null | null | null
> B3   | 166 |  251 | null | null | null | null | null | 128 | null | null | null | null | null
> B4   | 116 | null | null | null | null | null | null | 160 | null | null | null | null | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d293493f465baadf40a4a8cd2e6b669b)*

Answer (score 2):

Is there a way? Yes, dynamic SQL. Here's an example:

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from a;

CO         C1         C2         C3         C4
-- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
A1        102        275        400        -55
A2        162        209        330        -71

SQL> select * from b;

CO SELECT_C
-- --------
A1 C1,C2,C3
A2 C2,C4
```

Function that returns refcursor:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_code (par_code in varchar2)
  2  return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    l_str   varchar2(200);
  5    l_rc    sys_refcursor;
  6  begin
  7    select 'select ' || b.select_cols || ' from a'
  8    into l_str
  9    from b
 10    where b.code = par_code;
 11    open l_rc for l_str;
 12    return l_rc;
 13  end;
 14  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> var rc refcursor
SQL> exec :rc := f_code('A1');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print rc

        C1         C2         C3
---------- ---------- ----------
       102        275        400
       162        209        330

SQL>
```